# sed replace text and put to end of line

Tags: regex, sed

get the following output:

```
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2260301" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/5_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/1_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/2_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/3_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/4_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/6_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/7_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/8_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/9_2260301.jpg;http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/10_2260301.jpg|
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2260279" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/10_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/1_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/2_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/3_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/4_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/5_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/6_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/7_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/8_2260279.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/9_2260279.jpg|
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2259929" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/1_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/2_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/3_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/4_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/5_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/6_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/7_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/8_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/9_2259929.jpg;http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/10_2259929.jpg|
```

and need the following:

```
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2260301" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|5_2260301.jpg;1_2260301.jpg;2_2260301.jpg;3_2260301.jpg;4_2260301.jpg;6_2260301.jpg;7_2260301.jpg;8_2260301.jpg;9_2260301.jpg;10_2260301.jpg|http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/|
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2260279" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|10_2260279.jpg;1_2260279.jpg;2_2260279.jpg;3_2260279.jpg;4_2260279.jpg;5_2260279.jpg;6_2260279.jpg;7_2260279.jpg;8_2260279.jpg;9_2260279.jpg|http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/|
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2259929" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|1_2259929.jpg;2_2259929.jpg;3_2259929.jpg;4_2259929.jpg;5_2259929.jpg;6_2259929.jpg;7_2259929.jpg;8_2259929.jpg;9_2259929.jpg;10_2259929.jpg|http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/
```

i use this command to get only the jpg filname,

```
sed 's|http://img*......................||g'
```

this is not elegant. i will search for another soloution. and i need to know how to save the directory urls and put each on the end of lines `http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/`

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; 
do 
  var=$(echo "$line" | grep -oE "http://img[0-9].domain.xy/t/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/" | uniq); 
  echo "$line" | sed -e 's|http://img[0-9].domain.xy/t/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/||g' -e "s|.*|&"${var}"|g" >> newFile; 
done < file;
```

Read each line of the file using `while` and then `grep` the pattern `http://img...`, put that in a variable, using `sed` cut that pattern out and put the variable at the end of the line.

Result is written to a new file:

```
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2260301" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|5_2260301.jpg;1_2260301.jpg;2_2260301.jpg;3_2260301.jpg;4_2260301.jpg;6_2260301.jpg;7_2260301.jpg;8_2260301.jpg;9_2260301.jpg;10_2260301.jpg|http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2260279" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|10_2260279.jpg;1_2260279.jpg;2_2260279.jpg;3_2260279.jpg;4_2260279.jpg;5_2260279.jpg;6_2260279.jpg;7_2260279.jpg;8_2260279.jpg;9_2260279.jpg|http://img9.domain.xy/t/279/320/
<iframe  src="http://domain.xy/load.php?file=2259929" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>|1_2259929.jpg;2_2259929.jpg;3_2259929.jpg;4_2259929.jpg;5_2259929.jpg;6_2259929.jpg;7_2259929.jpg;8_2259929.jpg;9_2259929.jpg;10_2259929.jpg|http://img9.domain.xy/t/929/320/
```

Comment: thx, works fine. okay, we using while to read each line of file. grep -oE to get the url pattern, uniq to remove duplicates. thats all save to the var $line. with first sed command we get only the jpg filename. but what do we here? "s|.*|&"${var}"|g".

Comment: @Malik `&` prints the same thing that is on the left hand side of the `sed pipe |`(`.*` in this case), and then add "$var" after that, meaning to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last part of an url like "http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/5_2260301.jpg" you can use this regex: `/([0-9_]+\.[a-z]{3,4}+)`

Works with all number and all extension (.jpeg, .png, ...)

Comment: hmm that dosent work for me output is this http://img1.domain.xy/t/301/320/5_2260301.jpg when i type the command sed 's|/([0-9_]+\.[a-z]{3,4}+)||g'